# if (counter == < database value >)

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How do I make the value from my database as a int that I can use for my if else function ?

For example: In my database "armnumber = 3", how do I use it in my if else function ?

**code**

```
string myConnectionString;
myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=medicloud;SslMode=None;charset=utf8";

try
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string sqlStr = "Select armnumber from assign where id=1";
    cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

catch (MySqlException ex)
{
}
#endregion
if (counter == )
{
}
```

Comment: A select is not a "non" query, you arent picking up your results.. You need to execute the query, and read the number its picking up in your table, then you will have your int

Comment: @S.Akbari ahhh ... Sorry about that ): Thanks for the advice (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this code

```
connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
int databaseValue = int.Parse(reader["armnumber"].ToString());
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be [`MySqlDataAdapter`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) like this:

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand = cmd};
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
int armnumber = da.Fill(ds);
...
if (counter == armnumber)
```

Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
string sqlStr = "Select armnumber from assign where id=@id"; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
//Or better
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few initial notes:

- Continue operations after getting exception will not be a good practice, so I prefer the condition `if (counter == xx )` inside the `try` block.
- If the value of `ID` in the `where` clause is variable then make use of parameterization instead for concatenated queries.
- Since you are fetching only a single field make use of `ExecuteScalar` instead for `ExecuteNonQuery`
- You can make use of `using` als well for proper managing of connection and command objects.

So the code can be written as :

```
try
{
    string sqlStr = "Select armnumber from assign where  id=@id";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
    cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int armnumber = result != null ? int.Parse(result.ToString()) : 0;
    if (counter == armnumber)
    {
        // code here
    }
}

catch (MySqlException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: it says "int.Parse(result", cannot convert object to string o.o

Comment: When I run it, the ExecuteScalar() gives me windows 1232 error. How do I fix it ?